# How do I add commission members to the title page?

Tags: titles

I'm trying to get my master committee on my master thesis. So I want to add in 3 names one after the other with a header of "master committee". I currently have the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={120mm,227mm},
 left=40mm,
 top=40mm,
 }

\title{Example thesis}
\author{Thijser}
\date{June 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\end{document}
```

How would I go about adding this in? If I add anything to the document it will appear before/after the title page.

Basically what I want is

> ```
>                    Example thesis 
>                    Thijser
>                    June 2018
>
>                           master committee (different font)
>                    member 1's full name and titles 
>                    member 2's full name and titles 
>                    member 3's full name and titles
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `\maketitle` by redefining it based on the default:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
\let\footnotesize\small
\let\footnoterule\relax
\let \footnote \thanks
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}%
  {\LARGE \@title \par}%
  \vskip 3em%
  {\large
   \lineskip .75em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
      \@author
    \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
  {\large \@date \par}%
  %------ Adding committee ------%
  \vskip 1.5em%
  {%
  % Set font within this group
  \fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont%
  Master committee:\\
  {\Large member 1's full name and titles\\%
  member 2's full name and titles\\%
  member 3's full name and titles\\}%
}
  %------ /Adding committee ------%
\end{center}\par
\@thanks
\vfil\null
\end{titlepage}%
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
\global\let\thanks\relax
\global\let\maketitle\relax
\global\let\@thanks\@empty
\global\let\@author\@empty
\global\let\@date\@empty
\global\let\@title\@empty
\global\let\title\relax
\global\let\author\relax
\global\let\date\relax
\global\let\and\relax
}\makeatother


\title{Example thesis}
\author{Thijser}
\date{June 2018}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]